# Error with python executable : cannot import name ttk from tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable, ttk

I have a python (3.8.3) script which works perfectly. However, when I create an executable with the following command :

```
pyinstaller --onefile gui.py
```

I get the following error : **

> cannot import name ttk from tkinter

The error appears at this line :

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

I can not remove the import as "ttk" is really needed in my program.

I tried to create it with cx_freeze but I get the same error.

Do you have any solution for this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Is `tkinter` installed properly in your environment where you're compiling your script?

Comment: Tkinter was already installed in the environment (on Windows).  I tried "pip install tk" but doesn't help. Do you have any idea how to install it properly as you said ? Thanks

Comment: So you're compiling using global environment?

Comment: I tried with global environment and my own environment. I have no problem with Tkinter when executing the script. I do have an issue when I start the executable that I created.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these ways to compile your script:

1. `pyinstaller --onefile gui.py --hidden-import=tkinter.ttk`
2. `pyinstaller --onefile gui.py --hidden-import=tkinter`

If you tackle another import problem it would be better to compile using `.spec` file where you can specify hidden imports